# How to calculate a memory of a specific size

Tags: verilog, hardware, fpga

I would like to design a 4kb memory.
The size of a memory is equal to 2^m words or 2^m*n bits, m for address lines n for data lines.

In verilog we can write

> reg [WordSize-1:0] Mem [0:Address_width];

For 4kb memory what is the values of Wordsize and what for Address_width, how do we compute it?

Comment: It is not computable. You have to decide how wide your words are and how many you need. They depend on the requirements of the system into which the memory is going to go.

Answer (score -1):

I think better names are `WIDTH` and `DEPTH`, as this will better define the memory. So your declaration would be:

```
reg [WIDTH-1:0] Mem [0:DEPTH-1];
```

This gives you a memory that is `WIDTH` x `DEPTH`. Most often, you know the width. For example if you're trying to store bytes, then your `WIDTH` is 8. This is the first parameter you select. Then you think to yourself how many words you're going to need to store, which will set your depth. Rarely do you start with the memory size and go backwards, I can't think of a situation in which you want to think this way.

So let's say you want to design WIDTH = 8 and DEPTH = 1024, then that's an 8 kb memory, just multiply width and depth together.

As a side note, the width of the address that you need to access a memory that is `DEPTH` deep can be calculated by the log-base-2 of the depth. For example, if you have 1024 deep, your address width would be 10 bits wide (since 2^10 = 1024). In code:

```
reg [$clog2(DEPTH)-1:0] addr;
```

This is how I recommend sizing your address dynamically.